# How the 'new' keyword is used with the 'object variable' that already contains 'an object identifier' to some already existing 'object' of some class?

Tags: php, oop, object, new-operator

Consider below code from the [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) :

```
<?php
class Test
{
    static public function getNew()
    {
        return new static;
    }
}

class Child extends Test
{}

$obj1 = new Test();
$obj2 = new $obj1;
var_dump($obj1 !== $obj2);

?>
```

Output of above code :

```
bool(true)
```

As per my understanding, the object variable `$obj1` contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object of class `Test`.

Then, how this object variable named `$obj1` has been prefixed with the keyword `new` when it is being assigned to the variable `$obj2`?

The object variable `$obj1` must contain the object identifier to the object of class `Test`.

What has been achieved here by using a `new` keyword with the object variable that already contains some object identifier?

What actually gets compared in the `var_dump()` statement?

Why is the output of the comparison true?

I'm using **PHP 7.3.0**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new $obj1` will create a new instance of `$obj1::class` (which is `Test`).

The comparison within the `var_dump()` statetment is a **strict** comparison between two objects. It returns `true` because that strict comparison is checking that these two instances (`$obj1` and `$obj2`) are not references the same instance of the the same class.

If the comparison were not strict (e.g. `$obj1 != $obj2`) it would return **false**, since `$obj1 == $obj2` (e.g. the two have the same attributes and values, and are instances of the same class)

Read more about object comparison on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php) in the documentation.

That you are using 7.3 is mostly immaterial. You would have gotten the same results from 5.3 onwards

Comment: Are you saying that the code statement `$obj2 = new $obj1;` is interpreted by the PHP parser as `$obj2 = new Test;` since according to your perception `new $obj1` is interpreted as `$obj1::class` (which is `Test`)?

Comment: @yivi : According to your answer I tried, the code 

    <?php
      class Test {
        static public function getNew() {
            return new static;
        }
      }
    
      class Child extends Test {}
    
      $obj1 = new Test(); 
      $obj2 = new $obj1;
    
      $obj1::class;
    ?>

But instead of getting the expected output as `Test` I got the following error

    Fatal error: Dynamic class names are not allowed in compile-time ::class fetch

Why so?